# Usage of comma of full stop in direct speech

Tags: english, writing-system, writing

My daughter asked me if this is correct or not - "We've first got to put the shelves together, then find a way to put them up," said Hermione, in a matter-of-fact tone of voice. - my answer was direct speech ending with comma doesn't look correct, but her answer sheet says this as correct answer. I can't explain her why, googling didn't work out. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite is true — [this article explains in more detail](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823033938/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/comma) but generally you use a comma after direct speech. The only time this rule does not need to be followed is if the direct speech ends with a question mark or an exclamation point.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that are off-topic on this site. The appropriate response to such a question is to flag it as off-topic or (if applicable) to for migration to a site where it is on topic.